# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Google_client' not found despite adding library through composer

Tags: php, google-api, google-client, google-php-sdk

Getting error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Google_client' not found.

Using php -v 7.1.21

Installed google api php client via composer using

> composer require google/apiclient:"^2.0"

Using

> require 'vendor/autoload.php';

to include library.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: try to address the class as: Google_Client (Client with a capital C)

Comment: Thank You. That solved the problem. They should have mentioned it in their API.