# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Google\Client' not found

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, composer-php

## **Versions:**

**[Composer:](https://getcomposer.org/)** 2.4.0

**[PHP:](https://www.php.net/)** 7.4.30

**Apache:** 2.4.29

**[google-api-php-client:](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client)** Unknown

## **Basic Information**

On google-api-php-client, I am having trouble creating a client object. I always gives me this error when I try to create one.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Google\Client' not found

It's starting to bug me quite a bit now. I tried searching online but it currently seems I am the only one with the problem. I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client). Up until I got stuck right [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#basic-example), at basic examples. That's where I use the examples to see if I did everything right with no errors.

I am using composer to load dependencies as well.

Here is my code though.

```
require_once $coreRoot . 'objects/googleOAuth2/vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new Google\Client();    
$client->setAuthConfig(/* Secure Key JSON File */);
```

The **$coreRoot** variable includes the whole file path that leads up to the directory of the current php file.

## What I tried and found

A list of other stack overflow questions I have looked at while trying to search for an answer. None of the questions solved my problem. Some didn't have any answers, but it has comments.

[Class 'Google_Client' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44701156/class-google-client-not-found) - Same result

[Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Google_Client' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50095134/fatal-error-uncaught-error-class-google-client-not-found) - Code not similar to mine.

[Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Google_client' not found despite adding library through composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52299021/fatal-error-uncaught-error-class-google-client-not-found-despite-adding-libr) - No answers but has comments. The comment that helped the asker was confusing. Code most likely didn't match mine.

[Laravel: Class 'Google_Client' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56391240/laravel-class-google-client-not-found) - No answers but it has comments. Comments was not useful. I also tried the stuff the asker tried and I still got the same result.

## Other Information

Composer created Composer.json file

```
{
    "require": {
        "google/apiclient": "2.12.1"
    }
}
```

Original Composer.json file

```
{
    "name": "google/apiclient",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "Client library for Google APIs",
    "keywords": ["google"],
    "homepage": "http://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php",
    "license": "Apache-2.0",
    "require": {
        "php": "^5.6|^7.0|^8.0",
        "google/auth": "^1.10",
        "google/apiclient-services": "~0.200",
        "firebase/php-jwt": "~2.0||~3.0||~4.0||~5.0||~6.0",
        "monolog/monolog": "^1.17||^2.0||^3.0",
        "phpseclib/phpseclib": "~2.0||^3.0.2",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3.3||~6.0||~7.0",
        "guzzlehttp/psr7": "^1.8.4||^2.2.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^3.0",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "~2.1",
        "symfony/css-selector": "~2.1",
        "cache/filesystem-adapter": "^0.3.2|^1.1",
        "phpcompatibility/php-compatibility": "^9.2",
        "composer/composer": "^1.10.22",
        "yoast/phpunit-polyfills": "^1.0",
        "phpspec/prophecy-phpunit": "^1.1||^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^5.7.21 || ^6.0 || ^7.0 || ^8.0 || ^9.0"
    },
    "suggest": {
        "cache/filesystem-adapter": "For caching certs and tokens (using Google\\Client::setCache)"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Google\\": "src/"
        },
        "files": [
            "src/aliases.php"
        ],
        "classmap": [
            "src/aliases.php"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-main": "2.x-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

## Notes:

If I forgotten and details or is any part of this was confusing to you, comment below what part was confusing or what I was missing, and I will fix it.

Comment: 1) Why are you not using composer to load dependencies? 2) Why are you using PHP 7.2?

Comment: I am using composer to load dependencies. Sorry about that, guess I forgot to mentioned that part. Why I am using PHP 7.2, I was unable to update it. I tried updating it before but apache didn't like that and refused to start.

Comment: Include composer.json in your post. Which version of Apache? I have no problem using PHP 7.4, 8.0, and 8.1 with Apache. You might have more than one problem.

Comment: Okay, added those information in now. I probably do have more than one problem, although other composer stuff has worked previously and I didn't change anything since I last used composer.

Comment: You have not set up composer correctly. Start over and use composer to create your project and add dependencies.

Comment: Actually, I have two composer.json files. One in the downloaded one I got from github and another one that was created from composer. I gave you the one that was created from composer.

Comment: Please check whether current versions of the tools help you out. PHP 7.2 is horribly outdated, Composer 1.9.1 is nearly three years old, and having a unknown version of any package in your `composer.json` also looks pretty strange to me

Comment: Also, why do you use `require_once $coreRoot . 'objects/googleOAuth2/vendor/autoload.php';` and not the proper autoloader that is given in the root vendor folder of your application?

Comment: @NicoHaase I cannot update PHP. Apache will not let me, no matter how much I tried took. Just spent the last couple of hours trying to update it and still nothing. I did update my composer however though.

Comment: And did you try to use the proper autoloader that is generated by Composer?

Comment: I asked on reddit, but I do doubt anyone could help though.

Comment: @JohnHanley Until I managed to update PHP, got any others ideas on the composer problem?

Comment: run `composer diagnose` and run it to show the platform packages (`composer show -p`). [edit] your question with the current information, remove the outdated infos.

Comment: Basically, you want to run `composer init` followed by `composer require ...`. The correct vendor path should be `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` Google search. There are many tutorials on how to use composer correctly.

Comment: recommended is to run both as well with `-n` (non-interactive) so that the setup is already self-documented. you don't find that in the tutorials.

Comment: You guys do know that I am just trying to install google-api-php-client, right? I also finally updated my PHP to 7.4 now. Still gotten the same error though.

Comment: I managed to fix it. It is very embarrassing. I had my file location set to my localhost, not my full file directory.

Comment: Sorry, it completely slipped my mind. Again, truly sorry for wasting your time. I did put my solution in my answers to help others who may make the same mistake like me.

Answer (score 1):

you should use the below code on the current working directory

ı assume you have an `index.php`

```php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out my problem now.

For my variable `$coreRoot`, it was set as my `localhost` aka `127.0.0.1`. Which was very wrong. You can't call PHP functions or variables by a web address. That would pose a security vulnerability if it allowed that. You have to use the full file path. For example `C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php`, not `http://localhost/`. Can't believe I missed that.

Sorry for the trouble to everyone. And to everyone else who has similar problems to, call php from the full address, not the web address.

I do have to give a little credit to @dılo sürücü answer as it helped me remember this error.